# If we find two transitive relations what would we do in normalization

Tags: normalization

Say we have six columns A B C D E F, while removing transitive dependency we encounter the dependency where
F-> E,D,C,B,A (say F is the primary key)

> A->B (A is a transitive key towards B)
>
> C->D (C is a transitive key towards D)

In this case what would we do, would we make a new table with four columns or will we make two tables with two columns each?

Comment: Maybe you mean *functional* dependency? A *transitive dependency* is a transitive functional dependency. X->Y is transitive when there is also U where X->U->Y AND NOT U->X..

Comment: Maybe you are trying to say that candidate key (CK) F transitively determines B through A, and CK F transitively determines D through C? "Transitive key towards" does not make sense. Do you understand that you need to give a "cover" (a list of FDs that account for all the FDs), preferably a "canonical/minimal" one (one in a certain format)? It is not enough to say things like, F is a candidate key. It's the FDs that determine the keys; you need to give the FDs. PS "Transitive relations" does not make sense. Maybe you are trying to say "transitive (functional) dependencies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a relation schema `R(A B C D)` with dependencies:

```
A → B
C → D
```

then the following facts hold:

- The key of the relation is:

  `A C`
- The relation is neither in Boyce-Codd Normal Form, since both dependencies (`A → B` and `C → D`) violates the rule that the determinant should be a superkey, nor in Third Normal Form (since, in addition the the previous fact, `B` and `D` are not prime attributes).
- The relation can be transformed in Third Normal Form (and also Boyce-Codd Normal Form) by decomposing it in *three* relations:

  1. `R1(A B)`, with `A` as key and unique dependency: `A → B`
  2. `R2(C D)`, with `C` as key and unique dependency: `C → D`
  3. `R3(A C)`, with `A C` as key and no non-trivial dependencies

**EDITED**

Since you have changed your question, the answer has to be completely different. You should be aware that to solve a normalization problem, one should have two things (and *only* those two things):

1. The list of the attributes of the relation schema
2. A set of functional dependencies

*No* other information is needed, while to give a partial information is only confusing and does not produces a correct answer.

So, if I have understood your problem, you need to normalize a relation schema

```
R(A B C D E F)
```

for which the following functional dependencies exists:

```
A → B
C → D
F → A B C D E
```

In *this* particular case,

- the *only* (candidate) key of the relation is `F`;
- the relation is not in BCNF since both `A → B` and `C → D` violates the rule that the determinant should be a superkey, nor in 3NF (since, in addition the the previous fact, `B` and `D` are not prime attributes);
- the relation can be transformed in 3NF (and also BCNF) by decomposing it in *three* relations:

  1. `R1(A B)`, with `A` as key and unique dependency: `A → B`
  2. `R2(C D)`, with `C` as key and unique dependency: `C → D`
  3. `R3(A C E F)`, with `F` as key and dependencies: `F → A`, `F → C`, `F → E`.

Comment: Why did you separate  A and C, could you elaborate how are they violating the BCNF condition.
Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I get it but A and C would actually be foreign keys in R(A,C) right.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience but i edited the question a bit because it was a little confusing could you please edit your answer accordingly that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `A` and `C` would be foreign keys in `R(A,C)`. In your new editing of the question you made a mistake: “we have *four* columns A B C D E F”, do you have four or six columns? And there are other functional dependencies?

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: @SyedTayyabAbbas Components are projections of an original. So every shared column set holds exactly the same subrow values. So there are FKs both ways on every shared column set. (An equality dependency constraint.)